# How to train tensorflow object detection image segmentation mask_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco instance segmentation on my own dataset

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, image-segmentation

please help me with training my own dataset on mask_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco model.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

model:https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

I have refered to https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/instance_segmentation.md ; but I can't clearly understand the steps.

Do we have to give the Bounding box coordinates of the object along with the mask.png file?

How to convert the mask data to tfRecord files (for instance segmentation).?

Can anyone suggest the labelling tool used for bounding box as well as mask.png file!!

tools like LabelBox, labelme, labelimg gives either bounding box coordinated or mask.png file or the polygon coordinates for the object.
please help

Comment: what i know is use labelis you picture it will create XML file , then you create a mask , in polygon or in PNG, i will do it in PNG but then i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

The best you give png mask and xml labelization it should be working with create_pet_tf_record.py, set faces_only=false in this file... You can see into the code what is expected in this file..

change path into to point your directories in pipeline configuration

Answer (score 0):

> Do we have to give the Bounding box coordinates of the object along with the mask.png file?

Answer: Yes, you need the original images, bounding box files, and mask images.

Use the following tool to annotate each object in your original images [Label image](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg)

Once you're done with this, you need to annotate each pixel inside each bounding box. There are several tools you can use, for example you can use these tool [VGG annotator](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/)

Comment: do these tools help me to answer [this](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg/issues/377) question.?

Comment: yes, I did that, but later I discovered this post and was curious to know whether the above-mentioned tools were alternative to the `deeplab` or not. If not how?

Comment: deeplab is pixel-wise segmentation on the go, while mask-rcnn is object detection with added mask. You need bounding box for mask-rcnn and you don't for deeplab

Comment: great explanation, it seems like the `mask-rcnn` also draws a boundary along the edges of the objects (which is a pixel-wise segmentation) along with a bounding box. Is that a case or it just draws bounding boxes and the segmentation was done by deepLab? [For example](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-custom-mask-rcnn-model-with-tensorflow-object-detection-952f5b0c7ab4). I am little bit confuse in two approaches, Is it the case, if I need only segmentation, I will go with deeplab & if both (segmentation+bounding boxes) go with `mask-rcnn`.?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Mask-rcnn use faster-rcnn + pixel-wise segmentation once RPN proposes the bounding box. So, the pixel wise segmentation is only done inside the bounding box. Deeplab uses pixel-wise segmentation for the entire image